# How to get blob size in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Is there a way to get the size of the blob value in cassandra with CQL?  Better yet, is there a way to get an average size of the blob column, especially with a condition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do that in CQL. I assume you are interested in the original uncompressed size of the blob rather than the compressed size within Cassandra. I'd suggest adding an integer field to the table and store the size of the blob in it when you originally save the blob.

If you use that integer field as a clustering column, then you could do a range query on it to get the rows that have blobs of a certain size range.  To get the average size of the blob's in a range, you could use CQL to retrieve the size column, then use java/python/etc. to calculate the average of the returned values.

Comment: thanks, i guess i will have to wait for UDFs in Cassandra 3 to do this server-side.